# Trying to print an unordered_map

Tags: c++, iterator, hashmap, anagram

I am writing a simple program to find anagrams. I am using a hash table with sorted strings as the keys, and the unsorted strings as the values. When I try to print the unordered_map (hash map) it gives me this error.

> Error 1   error C2675: unary '++' : 'std::string' does not define this
>   operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined
>   operator  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\xhash 672 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>



void Anagrams(std::vector<std::string> &v){

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> wordTable;

    char sortedString[256];

    for (std::string tmp : v){

        strcpy(sortedString, tmp.c_str());

        std::sort(sortedString, sortedString + tmp.size());

        std::string backToString(sortedString);

        wordTable.insert(backToString, tmp);
    }

    std::cout << "Map contains" << std::endl;


    std::cout << "mymap's buckets contain:\n";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < wordTable.bucket_count(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "bucket #" << i << " contains:";
        for (auto local_it = wordTable.begin(i); local_it != wordTable.end(i); ++local_it)
            std::cout << " " << local_it->first << ":" << local_it->second;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }




}




int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> words{ "debitcard", "badcredit", "cat", "act", "evils", "elvis" };

    Anagrams(words);



    return 0;


}
```

For some reason it thinks the iterator "local_it" is a string. Can anyone help?

Comment: `char sortedString[256];` Why are you resorting to using char arrays?  Just use `std::string` throughout.

Comment: good point. I wasn't aware of that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the [std::unorderd_map::insert()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) function takes a `std::pair<key, value>`, not `key, value`:

```
 wordTable.insert(std::make_pair(backToString, tmp));
```